# Keeping same DateTime format for different locales

Tags: datetime, jsf, internationalization

Recently I launched support for internalization for my JSF application. Once language is switched from `en-US` to `de-AT`, `DateTime` format is changed as accordingly (default behaviour). Is it any quick solution to keep the same `DateTime` format for every supported locale?

Should it be `DateTimeConverter`, or is it a part of the settings (`faces-config.xml`)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are multiple options.

### Use `f:convertDateTime` with a fixed `locale` attribute

Format your dates using `f:convertDateTime` with a fixed `locale` attribute.

```
<h:outputText value="#{someBean.dateField}" >
    <f:convertDateTime pattern="..."
                       locale="#{applicationScopedBean.fixedLocale}" />
</h:outputText>
```

From the attribute documentation:

> `Locale` whose predefined styles for dates and times are used during formatting or parsing. If not specified, the `Locale` returned by `FacesContext.getViewRoot().getLocale()` will be used. Value must be either a VB expression that evaluates to a `java.util.Locale` instance, or a `String` that is valid to pass as the first argument to the constructor `java.util.Locale(String language, String country)`. The empty string is passed as the second argument.

### Override the `f:convertDateTime` converter in the `faces-config.xml`

You can override converters in the `faces-config.xml` using `<converter>`. You can override by ID or class. In this case ID is the way to go. The ID for `f:convertDateTime` is `javax.faces.DateTime`, so you could do something like:

```
<converter>
  <converter-id>javax.faces.DateTime</converter-id>
  <converter-class>org.example.MyDateTimeConverter</converter-class>
</converter>
```

When you implement your custom converter you should extend `javax.faces.convert.DateTimeConverter`. If you happen to be using PrimeFaces, extend `org.primefaces.convert.DateTimeConverter`.

Now simply hardcode the locale (to for example German):

```
public class MyDateTimeConverter extends DateTimeConverter
{

  public MyDateTimeConverter()
  {
    setLocale(Locale.GERMAN);
  }

}
```

Now you can use it like (note that the view locale is set to Dutch):

```
<f:view locale="nl">
  <h:outputText value="#{now}">
    <f:convertDateTime pattern="EEEEE dd MMMMM yyyy"/>
  </h:outputText>
</f:view>
```

Which will output:

> Mittwoch 10 Mai 2017

Comment: Sometimes solutions are luckily simple ;-)

Comment: Initially thought about this solution, but I have hundreds of places within my applications where I use it. Maybe I would simply extend this component with default value.

Comment: I would go for find and replace.

Comment: I cannot apply this solution, I need to find a different way to do it. Changing multiple files is againt SE principles, I need to find a single place in backend to modify it.

Comment: "'SE' principles" within your organization?

Comment: @Kukeltje probably... I'm wondering how that will work out if you need to change deprecated code.

Comment: @JasperdeVries: Hiring lots of "ZZP'ers"? Or "typemiepen"?